# nginx simple SSL connection

Tags: ssl, nginx

I am new to setup a simple SSL connection using nginx. The code I wrote below is accessible but it is not running with SSL. What am I missing?

My test site is just a simple `index.html`. My certificate and key is saved in `/etc/ssl/certs`.

```
 server {
     listen 80;
     server_name             example.com;

     location / {
         proxy_pass https://example.com:443;
     }
 }

 server {
     listen 443;
     root                    /home/deploy/test;

     ssl on;
     ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt;
     ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/certs/server.key;
 }
```

Comment: [Configuring HTTPS servers](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have to redirect non-HTTPS to HTTPS, not proxy pass.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name example.com;
  root                    /home/deploy/test;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/certs/server.key;
}
```